# if ($.browser.msie) not working+ie6

Tags: asp.net, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have master in my project.i have added js file in my master page.so that i can able to call the function in my content pages.My problem is when i am using this function ""if(!$.browser.msie){alert("Not ie Browser");}"" not working in ie6.In ie6 it is showing alert("Not ie Browser") all the time when the page load happens?Can i get some reason behind this?

Thank you

Comment: $.browser is not a built-in JavaScript property. Are you using a JS framework like prototype or jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0") alert("I am IE6");
```

Comment: if(!$.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0")
{alert("Not IE6");}      Still this alert showing all time

Comment: i have used master page and seperatee javascript file

Comment: @Joby Remove ! operator from the beginning in your if condition

Comment: I have used this function "function pageLoad(){ }" inside this condition "if(!$.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0")".Now i changed to reverse way...now it is working.......